Uploading an image with the format jpg, jpeg, png, heic to Vapor 4. Sending a file from an iOS application written in SwiftUI
I can't write the code for uploading images in any way.
Need to do this: a request is sent from the iOS application (SwiftUI) to the backend, then the file format (jpg, jpeg, png, heic) is checked in the backend, and if OK, I upload the image to the folder.

This is the code in Vapor:
func addImage(req: Request) async throws -> HTTPStatus {
    let user = try await getUserByToken(req: req)
    guard let profile = try await Profile.query(on: req.db)
            .filter(\.$user.$id == user.requireID())
            .first()
    else {
        throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "Profile not found")
    }
    
    let img = try req.content.decode(File.self)
    let path = req.application.directory.publicDirectory + "/images/profiles/"
    let fileName = try profile.requireID().uuidString + "." + (img.extension ?? "jpg")
    try await req.fileio.writeFile(img.data, at: path + fileName)
    return .ok
}


This is the code in iOS:
func addImage(_ image: UIImage) async throws {
    guard let url = URL(string: "\(url)/add-image"),
          let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
    else {
        throw URLError(.badURL)
    }
    
    let profileImage = ProfileImage(filename: "filename.jpg", data: imageData)
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("Bearer \(tokenManager.getToken())", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(profileImage)
        let (_, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    } catch {
        throw error
    }
}


This code downloads only jpg files. How exactly do I determine the file format?
Please help me write two methods: one for the client (iOS) and the other for the server (Vapor).
Perhaps there is some documentation/libraries for handling file formats.
P.S. Sorry for the bad English, not my native language :)

We are all using Swift as our native language, not an issue

To determine what's the file format, you can check the bytes. See how does SDWebImage https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/Core/NSData%2BImageContentType.m It's in Objective-C, but you should get the idea. For instance, a JPG starts with 0XFFD8 and ends with 0xFFD9  see https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG Usually, since you know you have images and know the possibilities, just checking the start should be enough

Just look here: https://theswiftdev.com/file-upload-api-server-in-vapor-4/

Sending File Over HTTP(s)
When sending binary files (like images) to the server you should use the Content-Type Header when uploading.
Common Content-Types include:

image/gif
image/jpeg
image/png
image/svg+xml
image/heif

Validation
When confirming the file type server-side, you must read the data. I have confirmed that @zdaecq's answer works using import Vapor (instead of Foundation).
